# Cuts and intersections on a curved surface

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm a fairly new Blender user and I'm trying to build this car as close in detail as I can and I've got most of the shape down, however I would like to start adding the panel gaps and vents.  I tried intersecting some other geometry using the boolean modifier, however it doesn't really work (I tried the same with some cylinders on the rims, also didn't work).

The panel gaps are a little better, the hood and trunk come out ok, but when I tried knifing in the door cuts, it distorted everything.  I've tried using the shrinkwrap modifier, which worked on the hood and trunk, but it didn't really help the door cuts.

I come from a surface modeling background (Alias) where trimming and intersecting doesn't alter the geometry, so this is a little frustrating for me!  Does anyone have any advice?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going on the lower right to properties > vertex groups > normals > checked "auto smooth"? Maybe that could help.

Comment: No not yet, I'll try that! Fingers crossed

Comment: nope, doesn't change anything.